# PHP curl Connection refused when trying to connect through a proxy

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I have the following code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

if ($use_proxy) {
    $proxies = [
        '(proxy-IP):3128' 
    ];
    $proxy_key = array_rand($proxies);
    $proxy = $proxies[$proxy_key];

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
}

$html = curl_exec($ch);
```

But when I run it and try to use curl through a proxy, I get the following error: **Failed to connect to (proxy-ip) port 3128 after 1003 ms: Connection refused.**

However, the port is fine, and the IP is fine. Obviously there's something missing, but I have been experimenting with variations of the code, and I still cannot connect to the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Try CURLOPT_CONNECT_TO instead of the proxy set of commands. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECT_TO, ["$remote_ip:$remote_port:$proxy_ip:$proxy_port"]);
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. $remote_ip in this case is the web provider's IP.

Comment: In my use case, I had a SSH tunnel which was binding a local ip and port to a remote ip and port. The remote ip and port was exposed to local calls because of this. When the call was outgoing I needed to use the remote ip in the url, but connect to the local ip in process.